# How to move a node along a vector?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vectormath

I have a bunch of nodes in a circle around a centre point. I got these positions by drawing arcs first then using the arcs [X,Y] position, populated an array which was used for the positions of the nodes. Using the forcelayout from the javascript library D3.

What I want to do now, if the nodes meet a certain criteria, for example, name starts with L, move them out to the outline of a bigger circle. I have made a simple diagram to explain.

[image: I want to move from x2,y2 to x3,y3]

I wish to be able to move from [X2,Y2] to [X3,Y3]. I labelled [X1,Y1] as I am sure you would need this to work out the vector from x1y2 to x2,y2 wish would then be used to calculate the movement along that vector, but I'm unsure how to do this movement

Comment: However i feel you should be using the tree layout  your problem set reminds me off this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

Comment: @Cyril can't use that at the moment, my data is set out to work with a tree. It should just be simple math, i think im on the right track. Shall answer if solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the problem is still active, but I'll answer anyway. Since the Problem has a cylindrical symmetry it is best to use polar coordinates. So  x,y become r,phi whereas r = sqrt(x^2+y^2) and phi=arctan(y/x). If you want to move a point X(r,phi) in the radial direction by lets say r' you do it by simple adding it to the existing radius. Thus X'=X(r+r',phi)

Comment: this sounds correct. I did manage to solve this but not with polar coordinates. Ill select yours as the correct one, and ill add my answer below when i can :)) thank you

Comment: I've added my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I solved it. I had a variable `moveOut`so I could toggle between the original node position and the one I move to. So depending on the value of `moveOut` I alter the scale of movement away from center.

```
 var thisNode = circleViewNode.filter(function(d){
        //console.log(d)
            return d.origin != 'EquivalenceSets' && d.hasRelationship != true;
        });

    thisNode.each(function(d){
        thisNodeSize = d.thisRadius;
    });

    if(!moveOut){
                thisScale = innerModelRadius - thisNodeSize*1.5;
                moveOut = true;
            } else {
                thisScale = innerModelItemRadius + (outerModelItemRadius - innerModelItemRadius)/2;
                moveOut = false;
            }


    thisNode.each(function(d){

        //console.log(d);
        var centerOfCircle = [width/2,height/2]; //get center
        //var centerOfCircle = [arcCenter.x, arcCenter.y];          
        var thisPosition = [d.x, d.y]; //get position of current node
            //thisVector = [center[0]-thisPosition[0], center[1]-thisPosition[1]],
        var thisVector = [thisPosition[0] - centerOfCircle[0], thisPosition[1] - centerOfCircle[1]];
        var thisVectorX = thisVector[0];
        var thisVectorY = thisVector[1];

        var xSquared = Math.pow(thisVector[0],2);
        var ySquared = Math.pow(thisVector[1],2);
        var normalVector = Math.sqrt(xSquared + ySquared); //using pythagoras theorum to work out length from node pos to center
        //console.log(d);

        thisVectorX= thisVectorX/normalVector;
        thisVectorY= thisVectorY/normalVector;

            // d.x = centerOfCircle[0]+(thisVectorX*thisScale);// + -38.5;
            // d.y = centerOfCircle[1]+(thisVectorY*thisScale);// + -20;

            d.x = centerOfCircle[0]+(thisVectorX*thisScale); //thisScale gives the ability to move back to original pos
            d.y = centerOfCircle[1]+(thisVectorY*thisScale);
        //}


    })
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", function(d)
    {

    //console.log(d.hasRelationship);
    //console.log(d.y);
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; //transition nodes

    });
```